# Member not replaced as expected, why?

Tags: modelica

Aims: all the derived classes should inherit some default equations from their base class. When the default equation is not valid for a derived class then it should redeclare it.

Here is a somewhat silly minimalistic example.

```
package Pkg

  class Equations
    Real x;
  end Equations;

  class DefaultEquations
    extends Equations;
    equation
      x = 0.0;
  end DefaultEquations;

  class Base
    replaceable DefaultEquations equations extends Equations;
  end Base;

end Pkg;

model DuplicateEquations

    import Pkg.*;

    class CustomizedClass
      extends Base;
      redeclare Equations equations;
      equation
        equations.x = 3;
    end CustomizedClass;

    CustomizedClass customized;

end DuplicateEquations;
```

For some mysterious reason, the default equation is not overriden:

```
omc Test.mo Package.mo
class DuplicateEquations
  Real customized.equations.x;
equation
  customized.equations.x = 0.0;
  customized.equations.x = 3.0;
end DuplicateEquations;
```

**Why is this happening? Why are both** `x=0` **and** `x=3` **generated?**

If I comment out the `package` declaration I get only the expected `x=3` equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The type has to be redeclared, not the component](http://www.openmodelica.org/index.php/forum/topic?id=594), as pointed out by Adrian Pop.